# gwt arquillian webdriver test does not run

Tags: gwt, maven, selenium, webdriver, jboss-arquillian

I tried to write a simple demo-testcase, to try out arquillian webdriver.

My pom looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>de.telekom.csc</groupId>
        <artifactId>csc0700</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

  <!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>csc0700-test</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>Csc0700Test</name>

  <prerequisites>
    <maven>3.0</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <properties>
    <arquillianVersion>1.0.2.Final</arquillianVersion>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
      <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0-alpha-1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-container-spi</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-testenricher-cdi</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-junit-standalone</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
       <artifactId>arquillian-drone-webdriver-depchain</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
       <type>pom</type>
       <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
      <version>8.1.5.v20120716</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
      <version>8.1.5.v20120716</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<!--    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.telekom.csc</groupId>
      <artifactId>csc0700-web</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>war</type>
      <scope>system</scope>
    </dependency> -->
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha-1</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${arquillianVersion}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-drone-bom</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>1.1.0.CR2</version> -->
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>    
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

When running a testcase, I get an exception:

```java
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:64)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:50)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:102)
    at de.telekom.csc.MainIT.createDriver(MainIT.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$StatementLifecycleExecutor.invoke(Arquillian.java:351)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.execute(ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.on(ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createBeforeContext(ContainerEventController.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.before(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:222)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:185)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

This seems to be due to a version conflict in http-client, but calling:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose  | grep client
```

only returns a single version: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient 4.1.2

I am stuck on this for a couple of days now.
Does anyone have a working combination of versions? or, is there a general approach to solve those issues with maven?

Googling the exception-line seems to indicate that quite a few people are experiencing the same problem, but I could not find a satisfactory answer. Additionally, this info seems to get out-of-date really quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`com.google.gwt:gwt-dev` *contains* its own (old) version of Apache HttpClient; this is why it's recommended not to include it in your classpath and/or separate your GWT client code and your server code in separate Maven modules.

If you can't fix the dependency easily, then you should be able to use the [JarJar Maven Plugin](http://sonatype.github.com/jarjar-maven-plugin/) or the [maven-share-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) in an *intermediate* artifact to relocate the offending classes.

See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4484

Comment: I actually did put my integration-tests in a different module, and `mvn dependency:tree`  doesn't show any gwt-dependencies. Is it possible that gwt is still pulled in?

Comment: I have to look a bit further. It seems that gwt was included as a dependent project through eclipse.

Comment: This was indeed the cause of the problem. Without gwt, the chrome driver starts running.